# Parent Class having an Array of Child Class

Tags: c++

With c++, I am trying to create a class called "family". Family is parent class of  child class "man," and I'm trying to create an array of "man" in family class, but in order to do that, I need to include man.hpp in family.hpp. But this messes things up really bad... as now man doesn't acknowledge family as a base class.

So my question is this:
How can I Include an array of child class in a parent class?

Thanks in advance!

```
#ifndef Family_hpp
#define Family_hpp
//here I want to include "include "man.hpp"" but this messes up."

class Family {
public:
//functions and constructor

private:
Man** manarray;

};
```

and here's family_cpp

```
#include "Family.hpp"
#include "Man.hpp"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

Family::Family()  {

}

void Family::setMen(int n) {
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *(manarray+ i + 1) = new man();
}
```

Comment: Please provide your attempt at coding this.

Comment: *Family is parent class of child class "man,"* This is a totally wrong use of inheritance.

Comment: A handy tool for telling whether or not inheritance makes sense: [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Comment: Besides the inheritance misconception, using raw pointers in C++ is considered very bad practice. I encourage you to learn how to use resources such as `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr` as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a *forward declaration* if the `Man` class in your family.hpp file.

```
//here I want to include "include "man.hpp"" but this messes up."
class Man;

class Family {
...
```

This tells the compiler that `Man` is a class, without having to declare it fully. This will work in your case, as (currently) the compiler doesn't need to know anything else about `Man` to compile the header file.